# What the format for Odata call to retrieve the name field from the Createdby table within the ContactSet entity in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

EDIT: I am trying to retrieve values from Dynamics CRM using the Odata feed. I want to lookup who created each contact by using the CreatedBy lookup within the ContactSet.

```
?$ Select ContactId, CreatedBy&$expand=Name
```

fails

EDIT: I tried query

```
lk_contactbase_createdby/FullName$$expand=lk_contactbase_createdby
```

and it seemed to give me all entries within the ContactSet (not sure why)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by expanding on name? Expand is for related entities. `name` is an attribute on the entity.

Comment: I am trying find who the contact was created by, therefore using lookup CreatedBy(lk_contactbase_createdby), and am trying to retrieve name from CreatedBy for each contact.

Answer (score 0):

You have to both expand the relationship and select what you need:

```
ContactSet?$expand=lk_contactbase_createdby&$select=FullName, lk_contactbase_createdby/FullName
```

In the example above, you'll get the FullName of the contact and the FullName from the creator.